# opening binary files seek difference python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to compare two methods which allow me to read binary files in python. If I use seek, I can see the time diff app 1 sec. Otherwise its not so much different. But do I need to use seek at all?

```
from xmlrpclib import Binary
from os.path import join
from hashlib import md5
import timeit
import os
import glob
class DefLogFile2(object):
    def __init__(self, path, filename):
        self.name = filename
        self.path = path
    def b64_encoded(self):
        with open(join(self.path, self.name), 'rb') as f:
            f.seek(0) # do I need this ? 
            z = lambda x: (Binary(x), md5(x).hexdigest())
            return z(f.read())
class DefLogFile( object ):
    def __init__(self, path, filename):
        self.name = filename
        self.logfile  = open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'rb')
        self.md5      = md5(self.logfile.read()).hexdigest()
        self.logfile.seek(0) # do I need this?
        self.b64encoded = Binary( self.logfile.read() )
        self.logfile.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)
    def z():
        p = r'C:\MyFiles'
        f_l  = glob.glob("{}\\*.BIN".format(p))
        w = []
        for f in f_l:
            w.append(DefLogFile2(os.path.dirname(f),os.path.basename(f)))
        for i in w:
            i.b64_encoded()
    def b():
        p = r'C:\MyFiles'
        f_l = glob.glob("{}\\*.BIN".format(p))
        w = []
        for f in f_l:
            w.append(DefLogFile(os.path.dirname(f),os.path.basename(f)))
        for i in w:
            i.b64encoded
    for i in xrange(10):
        print "z => {}".format(timeit.timeit(stmt = 'z()',setup = 'from __main__ import z', number=1000))
        print "b => {}".format(timeit.timeit(stmt='b()', setup='from __main__ import b', number=1000))
```

This is what I get when I don't use seek :

```
z => 4.74381579487
b => 4.61342728205
z => 4.60564184615
b => 4.43551179487
z => 4.52421620513
```

If I use seek,

```
z => 4.59685374359
b => 5.35988594872
z => 4.45907282051
b => 5.22442707692
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need `seek` here: it shouldn't harm the performance but it's simply redundant as `open` automatically positions the file pointer at the beginning of the file, so doing:

```
f = open("stuff")
f.seek(0)
```

...does this:

```
# open the file, blah, blah
current_position = 0
# the file is now open

# hey, let's change the current position with `f.seek(0)`!
current_position = 0 # doesn't do anything useful here
```

Comment: Thanks. But why the difference in time when using seek?

Comment: @vkk07, who knows? Are you sure these timings are consistent? Also, function calls are expensive in terms of time, so if you're running a function that does almost nothing a lot, your code can be wasting a considerable amount of time just on the function call itself (saving the current state, passing the arguments, etc).

Comment: @vkk07, for example, I had a lot of such functions in my project. The only thing they did was generating the same dictionaries and working with their data. Yes, that was just bad design. So, when I got rid of these tiny functions and made the dictionaries static, the execution speed _doubled_! Just because I halved the amount of function calls.